# Creating Python pip bundle with my projects

Tags: python, installation, bundle, distribution, pip

I am developing some apps which depends on one of them. 
I see pip can create bundles.
I have all my projects source in one dir.

How to create bundle for these projects and then install in other Ubuntu system?
probably I should use virtualenv. Is it possible to have one virtualenv for all of them?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To create a bundle, use something like:

```
pip bundle <name of bundle>.pybundle -r requirements.txt
```

where requirements.txt contains your list of apps to install. Or you can create a bundle with a single app (why?):

```
pip bundle <name of bundle>.pybundle <my app>
```

Then, on the other system, to install your bundle, you use:

```
pip install <name of bundle>.pybundle
```

Note the .pybundle extension for your bundle - you need this for pip to recognise it - install the bundle without an extension didn't work for me.

However `pip bundle` has been deprecated in 1.4 release and it will be removed in 1.5 release, [see change log](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/news.html#id2)

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Nearly a year later, your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Oddly, this doesn't seem a much-used feature, but is a nice equivalent for Rails' `bundle package` and `bundle install --local` commands.

Comment: Corrected by a friend - Bundler is not a "Rails" thing. Lest I be hunted down for my ignorance :)

Comment: Also of note: you can tell pip to cache downloaded files when you install them: this can make a huge saving to the amount of time it takes to create a bundle.

Comment: Unfortunately "Due to lack of interest and maintenance,  'pip bundle' and support for installing  from *.pybundle files is now deprecated, and will be removed in pip v1.5. " .